# How to install acumos AI demeter version?

Tags: kubernetes, acumos

I have already installed clio(acumos 3rd version) successfully but I faced some issues in creating pipeline, so I want to upgrade to "demeter" release.

In order to install "demeter" release of acumos, I did

git clone --single-branch --branch demeter https://gerrit.acumos.org/r/system-integration

~/system-integration$ git branch

- demeter

~/system-integration$ git status

On branch demeter
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/demeter'.

But the content of environment files suggests it still a clio version code

~/system-integration/AIO/acumos_env.sh

## Version of the AIO toolset

export ACUMOS_AIO_VERSION=3.0.3

export PORTAL_BE_IMAGE=$ACUMOS_STAGING/acumos-portal-be:3.0.24

export PORTAL_FE_IMAGE=$ACUMOS_STAGING/acumos-portal-fe:3.0.24

How can I make sure, It installs all demeter related images ?
ex:

nexus3.acumos.org:10002/acumos/acumos-portal-be:4.0.14  4.0.14

Answer (score 2):

in Demeter AIO is deprecated, the new installer is z2a. there is a folder called z2a in system-integration.

Comment: https://docs.acumos.org/en/latest/submodules/system-integration/docs/z2a/start-here.html

Thanks @Phil I am referring this now.

Comment: The whole reason, i wanted to upgrade from clio to demeter is to generate "service urls" automatically, but in demeter release also, it asks me to input "service and registry" URL, I am not sure what value shall I input here.
https://docs.acumos.org/en/latest/submodules/system-integration/docs/z2a/installation-guide.html

Refere : "Editing the mlwb_value.yaml File" section 

        registryurl: "http://some-registryurl.acumos-dev1"

        serviceurl: "http://some-serviceurl.acumos-dev1"